# Wix Toolset: Skip success dialog in StdBA

Tags: wix, burn, wix3

I am using WixStandardBootstrapperApplication in bundle
It will install .NET 4.8 and one MSI package, Can find code below,

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
        <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
            ThemeFile="theme.xml"
            SuppressOptionsUI="yes"
            LicenseUrl=""/>
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
<Chain DisableRollback="yes">
        <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx48Web"/>
        <MsiPackage Id="myMBS"
                    SourceFile="$(var.Mbs.Updater.TargetPath)"
                    DisplayInternalUI="yes"/>
</Chain>
```

Inside that MSI package we have Custom Action to LaunchApplication after InstallFinalize

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="LaunchApplication" After="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

So we don't need to StdBAs bundle to show Success Dialog, How to skip that
I have researched but didint find any workable solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [WixInternalUIBootstrapperApplication](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v4/reference/bal/wixinternaluibootstrapperapplication) was added in v4.0-preview.1 for this scenario where the bundle has 0-n prerequisites and one main MSI. If the prereqs don't need to be installed then only the splash screen and MSI UI will be shown. Otherwise, the prereq BA shows its UI while installing the prereqs and then closes before showing the MSI UI.

Comment: I just started looking at this.  Is there a sample anywhere?  If not, how do you specify the splash screen?  I create a simple 0 prereqa 1 standard MI and I see a very fast screen flash then UAC prompt.

Comment: The splash screen is supported by all bundles, it's not specific to this BA. [`Bundle/@SplashScreenSourceFile`](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/wxs/bundle/).

Comment: Have you read through the FAQ at https://wixtoolset.org/docs/fourthree/faqs/? It includes a link to the source code for all the test bundles.

Nothing should flash really fast on the screen before the UAC prompt. That would be a bug.

Comment: Thanks. I'll file a bug. I was able to capture a screen shot.  It said something like processing packages or something like that.  BTW,  I'm interested in hiring a v3 -> v4 guide for a few hours.  Hit me up if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

I conclude it is not possible in StdBA

The default UI dialog will come throughout the installation process in StdBA. So skipping the page is not possible yet. Still if needed means then custom BA will help achieve that. I am not tried it yet

Supporting link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43522884/7013033

Answer (score 0):

More common would be to provide the user an option wether to start the application or not after successful installation of all packages. This could be done by the WixStandardBootstrapperApplication build in property LaunchTarget. Then you could also remove the custom action from the msi installer.

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
        <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
            ThemeFile="theme.xml"
            SuppressOptionsUI="yes"
            LicenseUrl=""
            LaunchTarget="{YOURAPPLICATIONPATH}"/>
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
<Chain DisableRollback="yes">
        <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx48Web"/>
        <MsiPackage Id="myMBS"
                    SourceFile="$(var.Mbs.Updater.TargetPath)"
                    DisplayInternalUI="yes"/>
</Chain>
```

Documentation https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/bal/wixstandardbootstrapperapplication.html